# Why are my OpenIddict tokens invalid when my k8s POD restarts

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, azure-aks, openiddict

I have recently moved from running OpenIddict from running under Azure App Service to running under Azure AKS (k8s).

When the POD restarts the previously issued tokens are invalid.

When I converted from App Service => AKS the only code I did have to change was the way the signing/encryption certificates are done (see below) but these methods are functionally equivalent, so I don't think it's responsible for the tokens getting invalidated.

So I'm thinking that the only other thing that is different between AKS and an App Service, is perhaps something with the fact that on AKS the node name (i.e. pod) changes on the restart.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the tokens are invalidated under k8s on restart? And just to be clear tokens are working in general, but are invalid on restart.

From

```
         var cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes($"/var/ssl/private/{thumbprint}.p12"));
        options.AddSigningCertificate(cert);
        options.AddEncryptionCertificate(cert);
```

To (under AKS the cert is in Kubernetes secret)

```
    var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("tls.crt"),
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("tls.key"));

        options.AddSigningCertificate(cert);
        options.AddEncryptionCertificate(cert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out the issue had to do with DataProtection that I use with OpenIddict. When running on the Azure AppServer, this alone works.

```
 .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.UseDataProtection();
}
 .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseDataProtection();
}
```

When running under AKS (k8s) however the data protection keys don't persist (see here for instructions on what do when running in a container):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#persisting-keys-when-hosting-in-a-docker-container

In my case, I choose to persist to SQL using EFCore, but there are many other ways to persist.

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Now when I restart my PODS tokens remain valid.

One thing I can't explain is why DataProtection keys seem to work under the Azure AppService (without a persistence mechanism), so hoping somebody can enlighten me on this.

Comment: The app service will use the "machine key" in the registry, so it will remain the same across restarts. Also, not your question, but how I ended up here, how did you configure OpenIdDict to use DataProtection? I get errors about not having keys still.